# Custom Authentication using AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter with permitted paths and Also enabling method security with roles

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-rest

I am trying to implement a custom token based authentication with authentication filter:

```java
public class AuthAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, 
        IOException, ServletException {
        //some code here
    }
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, 
        final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) {                                                final Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Registering it with

```java
@Configuration
@Order(2)
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // constructor and beans etc

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
            .disable().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS).hasAnyRole(getAllrolles()).anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(authAuthenticationFilter(), 
                 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .logout().disable();
    }
}
```

I have another websecurity config with order `1` for whitelisted urls:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityWhiteList extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    //constructor and permitted path etc
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(permittedPaths()).permitAll()
                .and()
                .anonymous();
    }
}
```

At last, I have a configuration for method security as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurity extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    
    private final RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;

    @Autowired
    public MethodSecurity(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        this.roleHierarchy = roleHierarchy;
    }

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new     
            DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

The problem here is, I get 403 for the endpoints having method security in the service method annotated with `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_SOMETHING'))` even though the users do have `ROLE_SOMETHING`.

It works, if `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_SOMETHING'))` is not present and roles authentication, permitted path everything works.

After debugging, I found that my method security runs before `AuthAuthenticationFilter` and thus the security context is not populated yet so the user gets `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`.

My question is: Is it possible to make the authentication filter fire before method security? Or am I entirely doing it wrong? Like I should instead use `oncePerRequestFilter` instead of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`?

Comment: I had a similar issue and I had the following line of code: authAuthenticationFilter.setContinueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication(true). I deleted it and everything worked. Actually the sense of this method is clear of its name))).